# Yii2 configure multiple mail components using swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I want to send the email from different email accounts to users. 
How I can configure multiple $mailer components? 
Here is what I have implemented currently in `main-local.php`

```
'mailer' => [

    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport'=>false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'yyyyyyyyyy',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ]
],
```

Comment: Why not just define a another Swift mailer (with a different name) like your example shows? How many email accounts do you need to support?

Comment: I tried it but its not working

Comment: what u did? give an edit to what the first comment says. have you created another mailer component with different name and used that name while creating mailer object?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
'mailer' => [

    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport'=>false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'yyyyyyyyyy',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ]
],
'mailerb' => [

    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport'=>false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'yyyyyyyyyy',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ]
],
```

Access:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()

Yii::$app->mailerb->compose()
```

Comment: yes its working, only have to add viewpath for second one it not gets the default viewpath.

Comment: 'viewPath' => __DIR__ . "/../../common/mail",

Comment: In that mailer new mailer object

Answer (score -2):

To use Mailer, you should configure it in the application configuration like you just did in main-local.php

To send an email, you may use the following code:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact/html', ['contactForm' => $form])
->setFrom('from@domain.com')
->setTo($form->email)
->setSubject($form->subject)
->send();
```

Where in:

```
->setFrom(array('mail1@gmail.com' => 'NAME','mail2@gmail.com' => 'NAME2'))
```

You may pass an array of addresses if this message is from multiple people. You may also specify sender name in addition to email address using format: [email => name].

> Gmail disallows overriding the FROM name except from verfied email addresses that you prove to gmail you own. Either choose a different email server or go to your gmail settings and change it to another valid email address that you can receive email from.